# SQL Server - trying to format a table, maybe with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

So I've got this table

```
Email                     Username
------------------------- -------------------------
a@a.com                   a1                       
a@a.com                   a2                       
a@a.com                   a3                       
a@a.com                   a4                       
b@b.com                   b1                       
b@b.com                   b2                       
b@b.com                   b3                       
b@b.com                   b4                       
c@c.com                   c1                       
c@c.com                   c2                       
c@c.com                   c3                       
c@c.com                   c4                       

(12 row(s) affected)
```

But I want each e-mail address to appear once, then all associated Usernames to be listed after it, if that's possible..

Any help whatsoever is appreciated, 
Cheers.

**Edit**

Ok, so apparently, all the usernames will come under one column, all concatenated together, sounds kinda dumb, but that's what I've been asked for.

The output I want would be

```
Email                     Username
------------------------- -------------------------
a@a.com                   a1, a2, a3, a4
b@b.com                   b1, b2, b3, b4 
c@c.com                   c1, c2, c3, c4 
d@d.com                   d1, d2, d3, d4
```

Comment: You're looking something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string/545672#545672

Comment: can you please post the output what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `FOR XML PATH`

```
select
    Email,
    Username = 
        stuff((
            select
                ', ' + t2.Username
            from #table1 t2
            where
                t2.Email = t1.Email
            group by t2.Username
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
        ), 1, 2, '')
from #table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id Varchar(10),username varchar(10))
insert into @t(Id,username)values ('a@a.com','a1'), ('a@a.com','a2'), ('a@a.com','a3'),


select DISTINCT Id,substring(
        (
            Select ','+t.username  AS [text()]
            From @t t
            Where t.Id = t.Id
            ORDER BY tt.Id
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000)Username  from @t tt
```